# How can I find an element within parent element ID using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, hierarchy

I am trying to find the DIV within another DIV id.

```
<div id="container1">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container2">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice there are 2 DIVs with the class "inside". I am trying to select the one within a specific container.

When there is only 1 set of containers, this works:

```
$carousel_container = $(carousel).find(".inside");
```

However, when I define the parent ID, then try to select the inside div, it does not work:

```
$carousel_container = $(carousel).find("#" + o.theid + " .inside"); // where o.theid = container1 or container2
```

Comment: I doubt that `o.theid` has the correct value.

Comment: It does. I can trigger an alert box and it does have the correct value.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: he doesn't

Comment: @JohnRobinson: what is `carousel` ? -> http://jsfiddle.net/4XPsL/

Comment: If `carousel` is not a variable then it should be `$('#carousel')`, [here it works](http://jsbin.com/iwuwoq/3/edit).

Comment: -1 the selected answer doesn't address the issue (cf. @jAndy's demo).

Comment: @Christophe: Yes, it did. I just tried the selected answer and it works.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it doesn't answer the question. If it addressed your issue, then certainly you omitted a significant point in the question. Again, see @jAndy' s demo that shows everything's fine without the >.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(carousel).find("#" + o.theid + " > .inside");
```

Where `>` means child of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$carousel_container = $(carousel).find("#" + o.theid).children('.inside');
```